# MVC3 select with condition give strange behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement a result filter with MVC3 and face a problem like this:

```
 public ActionResult  Index(int? SubID)
    {
        var product = db.Product.Where(s => s.SubID == SubID).Include(t => t.SubCategory);

        if (SubID.HasValue)
        {
            ViewBag.SubID = new SelectList(db.SubCategory, "SubID", "SubNameVN", SubID);                
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.SubID = new SelectList(db.SubCategory, "SubID", "SubNameVN");                
        }



        return View(product);
    }
```

This one above works fine, but the following one always give me result of the whole table, despite what condition I put on it:

```
public ActionResult  Index(int? SubID)
    {
        var product = db.Product.Include(t => t.SubCategory);

        if (SubID.HasValue)
        {
            ViewBag.SubID = new SelectList(db.SubCategory, "SubID", "SubNameVN", SubID);                
            product.Where(s => s.SubID == SubID);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.SubID = new SelectList(db.SubCategory, "SubID", "SubNameVN");                
        }



        return View(product);
    }
```

And even this one doesn't work too:

```
public ActionResult  Index(int? SubID)
        {
            var product = from m in db.Product
                          select m;

            if (SubID.HasValue)
            {
                ViewBag.SubID = new SelectList(db.SubCategory, "SubID", "SubNameVN", SubID);                
                product.Where(s => s.SubID == SubID);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.SubID = new SelectList(db.SubCategory, "SubID", "SubNameVN");                
            }

            product.Include(t => t.SubCategory);

            return View(product);
        }
```

So please tell me what is the difference between these 3 approaches, and please explain to me why #2 and #3 don't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
product.Where(s => s.SubID == SubID);
```

...does not add a condition on product, it just creates an IEnumerable with the condition applied, and immediately throws it away. What you want is probably;

```
product = product.Where(s => s.SubID == SubID);
```

Comment: I'm so stupid. This is just a basic knowledge and I felt for it. Thank a lot for pointing it out, Sir!